# Access password stored with keytool using PHP in a secure way?

Tags: php, keystore, keytool

What I gathered online is that to use/access a password that I saved using keytool, I need to do the following.

- Use keytool to export the private key
- Use openssl to convert the PKCS12 file to a PEM file
- Set PEM file permission to 600
- In PHP application, use libraries like openssl or phpseclib to read the private key from the PEM file.

But doesn't the above expose the password? Meaning a hacker could retrieve the password (and my passphrase is in my code) if they get hold of my PEM file when my server is compromised. Is there a more secure way?

Comment: Expose the password to who, exactly? Can you be more specific about what your concern is?

Comment: @ADyson Sorry. Meaning a hacker could retrieve the password if they get hold of my PEM file.

Comment: Well possibly. But then it's your responsibility to keep your server secure, and also not store the PEM file anywhere it could be downloaded with authorisation. And maybe think about whether you delete it as soon as you've finished with it, and don't leave it lying around in between usages. Your server getting compromised is hopefully something that should never ever happen, unless its security overall is poor.

Comment: @ADyson Yes, you're right. I'm running something related to cryptocurrency. With the vast amount of hacks happening, I can't take my chances. Deleting the PEM file immediately after using could be an option. But I wonder if it would consume too much resources if this happens like every few seconds.

Comment: You could measure how long the process actually takes and how much CPU and RAM it takes, just to see if it's likely to be an issue. And then if it's significant maybe you could consider a different way of storing your passwords, which doesn't require such a long process to retreive the data, and/or doesn't require you to write anything to the disk during the process. e.g. there are cloud services which offer password and key vaults securely, or there may be other options locally - you'd have to do some detailed research.